# How do I minimise Yahoo Messenger and have it just appear in the system tray?

Tags: windows, notification-area, yahoo-messenger

How do I minimise Yahoo Messenger and have it just appear in the system tray?

It used to be standard behaviour that when I minimised Yahoo Messenger it wouldn't minimise but go to the system tray.. or clicking "close" and it would go to the system tray.

That behaviour seems to have gone. How do I re-enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click Messenger at the top of Y!M
- Click Preferences.
- Click General Category on the left.
- Find the section "When I'm using Yahoo! Messenger."
- Check the box for "Remove the taskbar button when I minimize the main window."
- Click OK.

This will make it so that when you minimize Y!M you will not see it at all in your taskbar and the only place you will see it is the little yellow Yahoo Messenger icon in your system tray. You will still be able to get alerts etc.

Comment: that's getting there, it's gone from the taskbar but it's not in the system tray, and it's not listed in win xp under "hide when inactive"

Comment: Copy-pasted from [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090726121519AAZzx4o).

Comment: no i was the person who put it on yahoo answers for your information

Comment: @slhk from what he said, it wasn't a mindless copy/paste, but so what if it was a copy/paste.. it could've helped and got part of the way there.  It was very reasonable to think this would solve it.  He could've stated the source as yahoo answers, not such abig deal if he didn't, there probably aren't other relevant things on that thread there, and  he was the source for the answer on yahoo answers!

Comment: no prob. I restarted and it's fine now but aside from a windows glitch, as far as any actual fix in the settings of yahoo messenger is concerned, you got it.

Comment: I also after the restart saw it was set to always hide so I set it to always show. though before the restart, I didn't even see it listed even when I exited and restarted yahoo messenger. so that's just something relevant i'm adding.